# Why does "set -e" inside of a function called in an "||" statement keep going after a command fails?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to have a function which will exit on the first command that fails, so I did this:

```
foo() (
  set -e
  cp file_from_there file_here
  echo "copied file from there to here"
  chmod +x file_here
)
```

Now, I want to run this function as such:

```
foo || log_error "foo failed"
```

What I expect is that upon failure `foo` will exit with a non-zero exit code, so that the `log_error` command will execute.

But in practice, `foo` doesn't stop after the failed `cp`, and continues to the echo and chmod:

```
$ foo
cp: cannot stat 'file_from_there': No such file or directory
copied file from there to here
```

However, running it as such:

```
$ foo
cp: cannot stat 'file_from_there': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

We can see that it stops execution in this case.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: You run it the same way in both of the shown examples, but you get different behavior in one case.  I suspect the first is `foo | | log_error foo failed`.  Running the shell in a boolean condition changes the behavior of `set -e`.  `bash` is not a pain; `set -e` is a pain.  Avoid it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, what do you do in case you have a long list of commands that you wish to stop execute after first failure? just check the status code after each one?

Comment: `cmd || die`. Nice and explicit. Simple enough to define `die() { printf "%s${1:+\n}" "$*"; exit 1; } >&2` or however you like.  The explicit exit is far less confusing than `set -e`

Comment: Or even simply `cmd || exit` or `cmd || return`. Both `exit` and `return` are designed to return the exit status of `cmd`.

Comment: Because it's defined (and specified) in this way. If it were not the case, the right-hand-side of the `||` would be unreachable code.

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't have any specifications for early termination from any step within the script.  You should modify it to look something like this (*it will stop on the first error encountered, but can easily be adapted to capture recovery info but continue processing other files.*):

```
#!/bin/sh

foo(){
  COM="cp ${FILE} file_here"
  C_MODE="chmod +x file_here"

  ${COM}
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "copied '${FILE}' to here"
    ${C_MODE}
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
       echo "#FAILED||${C_MODE}|" >&2
    fi
  else
    echo "#FAILED|${COM}|${C_MODE}|" >&2
  fi
}

JOBLIST="joblist.files"
LOG="joblist.log"   ; rm -f "${LOG}"
ERR="joblist.recovery"    ; rm -f "${ERR}"


while [ true ]
do
    read FILE

    if [ -s "${ERR}" ]
    then   msg="INTERRUPT -- Recovery info provided for failed items." ; RC=1 ; FILE=""
    else   msg="COMPLETED -- All items successful." ; RC=0
    fi

    if [ -z "${FILE}" ]
    then
        echo "${msg}"
        exit ${RC}
    fi

    foo >"${LOG}" 2>"${ERR}"
done <"${JOBLIST}"
```